# Что такое ЭСЭМ(СМ)

Tags: терминология

Что такое СМ? О нем поется в песне:
http://teksty-pesenok.ru/rus-yurij-nesterenko/tekst-pesni-pesnya-o-ppogpammistskoj-mol/1958735/

...Одним нажатьем на кнопку повесить ЭСЭМ

Comment: Советская копия DEC PDP-11

Comment: наверное это самый необычный и неожиданный вопрос тут)

Comment: "СМ", как сейчас говорять "торговая марка" (TM) Министерства приборостроения СССР. Были аналогами какой-то буржуинской техники. СМ-1 и СМ-2 -- не помню, гугл в помощь. СМ-3, СМ-4, СМ-1420 -- dec pdp-11, СМ-1600 -- вроде двухпроцессорная, один процессор -- pdp-11, СМ-1700 -- dec vax-11...

Comment: Википедия: [СМ ЭВМ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%CC_%DD%C2%CC)

Comment: Познавательный вопрос )))